# Makefile: Avoiding multiple execution of a recipe when multiple dependencies are generated by the same recipe

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile with the following structure:

```
log_file output_1 output_2: input
    myprogram input
generate: log_file output_1 output_2
```

When I ask `make` for the target `generate`, it executes the first recipe three times. Is there a way to have a target that depends on multiple dependencies which are all created together by a single recipe, without having to invoke the recipe multiple times?

Comment: If all the output files have a common "base" of their name, like `foo.1`, `foo.2`, `foo.3`, then you can create a pattern rule and that behaves the way you want.  If they don't have a common base like that, then you're stuck playing tricks as described by Mischa.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the classic makefile problem. All solutions feel like hacks; take your pick ... (and pardon the dense text here)

`generate : input ; myprogram $^ # if you never invoke "make output_1"`

or

`output_1 output_2 : logfile; @: # the choice of mitm is arbitrary 
logfile : input ; myprogram $^`

Answer (score 0):

According to [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html#Rules-with-Grouped-Target) this can be achieved by using special `&:` separator, like this:

```
log_file output_1 output_2 &: input
    myprogram input
generate: log_file output_1 output_2
```